# How to upload a file to a shared drive using unix?

Tags: scp

I have a requirement which says it should be able to upload a file from a Windows shared drive using `UNIX` . How to approach that ?
What am I trying is

```
scp D:/testfile username@hostname : \home\username\test_Folder
```

But it is not working out at all.
How successfully can it be done?

Please explain.

Comment: You need to use Samba to copy data from Windows File & Print Sharing, not SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNIX naming convensions for pathes and without spaces within scp:
scp D:/testfile username@hostname:/home/username/test_Folder